How to get object using objectRegisteredForID in Core Data in Swift
I am trying to convert a line of Objective-C code into Swift.
The objective-C is
Contacts *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:self.latestcontactid];

The following code compiles but is not finding the object even though there is a valid context and id
if let myContact = self.managedObjectContext.registeredObject(for: self.latestcontactid!) as? Contacts {
//we never get here although we should
}

ChatGPT suggests the following code:
let object = self.managedObjectContext.object(with:NSManagedObjectID(string:_latestcontactid))

but it gives compiler error:

Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

What is the correct way to grab a managedObject in swift from its ManagedObjectID?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions

There is a slight difference between registeredObject(for:) and object(with:) and even a little with existingObject(with:). Here are some infos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012874/whats-the-difference-between-objectregisteredforid-and-existingobjectwithid

But your first attempt is the one mimicking the Objective-C code. ChatGPT code would be in fact self.managedObjectContext.object(with: self.lastestcontactid!) since latestcontactid should be already a NSManagedObjectID.

The difference between the 3 APIs might explain why the code is not finding the object in the first example. The MOC has just been created from scratch and is not persistent in the class. I will try creating the equivalent of in ivar in the Swift Class to hold the MOC once retrieved. How would I create the equivalent of an ivar in Swift.  Objective C code is @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;  Would (in Swift) var managedObjectContext? = nil be an acceptable way to do this--then set it to the appdelegate sharedInstance when first used?
